# Efficient data structure for redux state to store only necessary data per action

Tags: typescript, redux, data-structures

Trying to figure out better approach to store only nesesary information in redux state for these routes:

1. route `/courses` -- displays list of courses;
2. route `/course/:courseCode` -- includes information about course and course history per year;
3. route `/student/:studentId` -- includes information about a student and their course history per year;

currently have the state like this:

```
{
  loading: boolean;
  students: Student[];
  history: CourseHistory[];
  courses: Course[];
}
```

and at the moment this is what state looks like for every route:

**for route `/courses`:**

```
{
  ...
  students: []
  history: []
  courses: [
    ... list of courses;
  ];
}
```

**for route `/course/:courseCode`:**

```
{
  ...
  students: [
    ... list of students that correspond with course history records;
  ]
  history: [
    ... list of records that correspond with course 'CS101';
  ]
  courses: [
    {
      name: "Data Structures and Algorithms",
      code: 'CS101',
    },
  ];
}
```

**for route `/student/:studentId`:**

```
{
  ...
  students: [
    {
      name: "Alice Quinn",
      id: 'student1',
    }
  ];
  history: [
    ... list of records that correspond with the student 'student1';
  ];
  courses: [
    ... list of courses that correspond with course history records;
  ];
}
```

these are the data structure I used:

```
type Student = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  email: string;
}

type Course = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  creditHours: string;
  prerequisites: string;
}

type CourseHistory = {
  studentId: number;
  courseId: number;
  year: string;
  semester: 'spring' | 'fall' | 'summber';
}
```

Can I get some response from the community on state structure design? Is this the right approach for designing the state, that `courses` and `students` stores only one value depending on the action. Should I split that state somehow, or use union types for state, so I could specify the type for payload for each action (though that [article](https://phryneas.de/redux-typescript-no-discriminating-union) for example says that using union types for state actions is anti-pattern):

`/courses`

```
{
  loading: boolean;
  courses: Course[];
}
```

`/course/:courseCode`

```
{
  loading: boolean;
  students: Student[];
  history: CourseHistory[];
  course: Course;
}
```

`/student/:studentId`

```
{
  loading: boolean;
  student: Student;
  history: CourseHistory[];
  courses: Course[];
}
```